# Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-3

I have a problem with cordova/phonegap contacts.
This is the code i am trying to execute, i put in an external javascript file:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
// find all contacts
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "*";
var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts

function onSuccess(contacts) {
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
}
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts

function onError(contactError) {
alert('onError!');
}
```

This is the code from the phonegap API documentation:

[link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find)

The original code is to find all contacts with 'bob' in every field.
I changed it to "*"(Just a star) for all my contacts.

The function onDeviceReady is just called by a button click.

The error I get in the logcat is this:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(81)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined"  
81 is the linenumber with: var options = new ContactFindOptions();
```

Does anyone know what to do to get the function ContactFindOptions() work?

If you need more info, just let me know.

Comment: change cordova libaray

Comment: What do you mean? the cordova library i'm using is the newest available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access contacts on Android using Phonegap:-

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // specify contact search criteria
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName"];   // return contact.displayName field

    // find contacts
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

var names = [];

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].displayName) {  // many contacts don't have displayName
            names.push(contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    }
    alert('contacts loaded');
}
```

you can try to read the documentation and implementation of how to use I'm providing some link which will help you [Saving Contacts with PhoneGap Android](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/09/saving-contacts-with-phonegap-android.html)  and [Example of Creating a full contact with PhoneGap](http://write.intellectualmollusc.net/2012/03/example-of-creating-a-full-contact-with-phonegap/)

Comment: The problem is that i dont want to save contacts or create them, just get all the contacts from the user's phone. And eventually list them, but first get the function to work and get them back in the console.

Comment: Still not working and getting the same error back. There need to be a file which contains ContactFindOptions(), but i cant find that one.

Comment: and even Put the cordova.js file before the downloader.js file and it should work.        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloader.js"></script> in this manner...

Comment: I thought that i could use contacts directly. i am trying to install it now from github [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts)

Comment: It works now thanks. added the library for contacts.

Comment: Wargamer88 What library did you add to where ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because your cordova is not understanding this function. 
You need to add the plugin, you need to add the contacts plugin.
In your cordova project run this using command line:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
```

This will add following to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

and add following to **res\xml\config.xml**

```
<feature name="Contacts">
   <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue because the `deviceready` event in Cordova had yet to fire. Addresss this by wrapping any Cordova API calls in a `deviceready` event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    console.log("deviceready fired!"); //do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, added this line of code and it worked. it links to the cordova library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```